# How to create html with link-to property inside custom jquery plugin?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a custom jquery plugin that use to create drop down html for a search box. 
Inside that, html is created as follows.

```
$.each(stack, function (i, stackItem) {
                    var url = _getItemURL(stackItem, lang);

                    if (stackItem.INS !== undefined) {
                        html += '<li class="row"> <a href="' + url + '">' + stackItem.DS_HIGHLIGHTED + ' - ' + stackItem.E + '<br>' + stackItem.TICKER_DESC + '</a> </li>';
                    } else {
                        html += '<li class="row"> <a href="' + url + '">' + stackItem.COMPANY_DESC_HIGHLIGHTED + '<br>' /*+ _getCountry(stackItem.CC, lang)*/ + '</a> </li>';
                    }
                    itemCount++;
              });
```

As you can see href attribute is used to create links in this html. But when user click on those links application reloads the browser page. I want it to correctly map to different route in the application like in hbs files as follows

```
<li> {{#link-to 'stock-overview' 'en' 'tdwl' '1010'}}Stock{{/link-to}} </li>
```

How can I generate html like that inside previous java script code.

Appreciate any help?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you to think if you really need that jQuery plugin or could go with a plain ember solution. There are some pretty fancy addons like [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com).

But if you really want to do that you need to understand that a `{{#link-to}}` does not only generate a `<a>` tag but only handles clicks on it and then doing a `transitionTo`.

So no, its not possible to do this when you simply append the HTML to the DOM. You would have to catch the `click` events on the `<a>` tags manually and then trigger the transition. It depends a bit how you inject the `html` into the DOM.

One thing you could do is to create a unique `id` for each `<a>` tag and after you inserted the html into the DOM you find the `<a>` tags by the `id` and attach the `onclick` event.

A better way would be to create DOM instead of HTML, so manually call `document.createElement` and then attach the `click` event.

To trigger the transition you can do something like this inside any Object that has the owner injected (like a component):

```
Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('controller:application').transitionToRoute('stock-overview', 'en', 'tdwl', '1010');
```

However cleanly the best solution would be to go for a ember handlebars template and a `{{#each}}` loop instead of the jQuery solution. To tell you how to do that however we need more information. So best is probably you ask a new question and explain exactly what you want to achieve, and now ask about a problem you have with a probably wrong solution for another problem.